# Angular 1.5 & ES6 -Dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to angular and i'm trying to use ES6.

I have a problem with dependencies inject, i can't get it to work.

My index.js :

```
    import './index-state.css!';
    import angular from 'angular';
    import 'angular-ui-router';
    import IndexStateController from './index-state-controller';
    import indexRouteConfig from './index-route';

    const dependencies = [
        'ui.router'
    ];

    export default angular
        .module('index-state-component', dependencies)
        .controller('IndexStateController', IndexStateController)
        .config(indexRouteConfig);
```

My index-state.controller.js is :

```
    class IndexStateController {
        constructor($timeout) {
            this.$timeout = $timeout;
            this.controllerName = 'Example Controller';
            console.log(this.$timeout);
        }

    }

    IndexStateController.$inject =['$timeout'];

    export default [
        IndexStateController
    ];
```

I'm getting 'undefined' on the console.log(this.$timeout).

Can someone help me through this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are exporting an array containing the controller instead of exporting the controller class itself at that means you have overriden the `$inject` attribute with an empty set of dependencies:

```
export default [
    IndexStateController
];
```

should be:

```
export default IndexStateController;
```

Alternatively you could include the injection values in the export:

```
export default [
    '$timeout',
    IndexStateController
];
```

Another solution if you use something like `gulp` to build your code is to compile es6 with something like babel and then use `ngAnnotate` to do the injection automatically. In that case you would want to mark the class as requiring injection:

```
class IndexStateController {
    constructor($timeout) {
        "ngInject"
        this.$timeout = $timeout;
        this.controllerName = 'Example Controller';
        console.log(this.$timeout);
    }

}
export default IndexStateController;
```

Comment: You are right, it's working now ! Thanks a lot. I guess there will be a learning curve before mastering ES6